# Why am i getting an error that says "Process finished with exit code 1" in android studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

This is the error thread that is output
Error message : "Process finished with exit code 1" in android studio

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java" -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7536 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Didea.junit.sm_runner -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;E:\Program files\Android Studio Files\android-sdk\platforms\android-22\android.jar;E:\Program files\Android Studio Files\android-sdk\platforms\android-22\data\res;C:\Users\pcname\AndroidStudioProjects\projectname\build" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 @w@C:\Users\pcname\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_junit2.tmp @C:\Users\pcname\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_junit2.tmp -socket51102
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.textui.ResultPrinter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `junit:junit:4.12` in your build.gradle and sync/compile again.

```
dependencies {

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Comment: Thanks Fluffy,well i just imported the project from itellij ide so i cant find that file in my project in android studio

Comment: your_app_directory >  app > build.gradle This is where you put the dependencies

Comment: I have added the above lines of code and now it says "Error:(34, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler"

Comment: See the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your dependencies. Looks like you dont have a library with `junit.textui.ResultPrinter`

Comment: okay,thanks!.how do i add it